# How to restart service after reboot without showing any notification through forground service

Tags: android

Background: I have a service which register a ContentObserver. ContentObserver should be set even  app in not open or device is rebooted. Which can be achieved only by a background service.

Problem: As if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O` it can not just start backgroundService. It can only foreground-Service but a foreground service need notification. Which is not good as user will see notification. (Facebook never shows any notification on reboot but still its service get registered)

( Here can be found full code : http://www.digitstory.com/android-detect-new-contact-addition/ with more description that why I am using Handler ) 
My Service is:-

```
public class ContactWatchService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                //Register contact observer <--- I register here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Now on reboot BoradCastReceiver:-

```
public class MobileRestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ContactWatchService.class)); //TODO--> ERROR won't work as app is in background
    }
}
```

So if I use `startForegroundService` on `MobileRestartReceiver` then have to do  `startForeground(1,notification)`, which will need notification. (note here u can not just start service it will throw exception that app is in background)

So how I can I `registerContentObserver` from reboot without showing any notification?

Please care about:`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O`.

(Manifest is set with all permissions, so don't worry about this)

Comment: You should be using a foreground service. Currently you're just leaking the service by not terminating `thread` and unregistering observer during `onDestroy` so it will probably fail during simple tests. Don't look at other apps (especially from google, facebook or other that usually come pre-installed with the device) since often time they have elevated privileges baked into the system and you won't be able to replicate that.

Answer (score 0):

> So how I can I registerContentObserver from reboot without showing any notification?

You can't, sorry. Note, though, that you can [use `JobScheduler` to be notified about changes in a `ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)) on API Level 24 and higher.